# How can I pull data from specific rows via SQL and separate them into their own columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I apologize if I cannot explain this properly in advance but I will do my best.

I have a SQL table. In the table, there are multiple columns. One of which is labeled 'meta_key' and another which is 'meta_value'. I would like to know how to write SQL that will pull specific rows in one column and also gather the data from another column in the same row and separate all of these out into their own columns. (Please forgive me if this doesn't make sense.)

I've tried the following which was provided by a friend:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta
WHERE meta_key = 3 OR meta_key = 9 OR meta_key = 22 OR meta_key = 23
```

But it only gets me halfway there in that it provides all of the data from those rows and columns and consolidates it all into a single column.

Again, the SQL that was tried was:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta
WHERE meta_key = 3 OR meta_key = 9 OR meta_key = 22 OR meta_key = 23
```

I didn't receive error messages for above but it did not provide the desired outcome.

Here is a screenshot of the table before the above SQL:

[image: Here is a screenshot of the table before the above SQL:]

[image: and afterd]

And here is a screenshot after:

**UPDATE**

I've made some progress. I believe what they call an 'Aggregate Function' is what I can use.

This has gotten me closer to my goal:

```
  SELECT 
  max(case when meta_key = 3 then meta_value end) Ticker,
  max(case when meta_key = 9 then meta_value end) Reason,
  max(case when meta_key = 22 then meta_value end) Resistance,
  max(case when meta_key = 23 then meta_value end) Support
  from wp_gf_entry_meta
```

The only problem now is that it only returns one row and I'm not certain how to make it return more than one row.

Comment: what is the desired output you are wanting/expecting to get?

Comment: Hi Tik, I think a better way of describing it is that I want every row from the meta_value column in the first photo above to be in its own column. Only, I don't need every single one of those rows and I realize I would probably have to make column names for each. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: like a pivot table?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit that I don't know what that is. But it makes sense to me that I do want to 'pivot' the data into a different direction. So yes, maybe that's right. I'm just not certain.

Comment: still a bit confused but maybe something along these lines
this will count the instances of each meta_key and put it in to columns
you still need to manually put the column headers in

SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN meta_key = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DRYS,
SUM(CASE WHEN meta_key = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MIN_BID_REQ
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta

Comment: Hi Tik, Thank you! I tried that out and it kind of helped in that it put DRYS in its own column. But for some reason, the only other column after that was called MIN_BID_REQ.

Comment: i didnt write the whole query out.
how many columns would you be expecting to have
and once you have you columns what are you expecting to be in the rows

Comment: Hi Tik, If you look at the 'meta_key' column, I will at very least need 3, 9, 22 and 23. I know I will need others but if there's some type of SQL that you can start that with I might be able to follow your logic and add the rest. So in other words, if you look at the 'meta_key' column and find the number 3, then look under the 'meta_value' column on that same row, it will give you DRYS. I will need whatever is to the right of 9, 22 and 23 following that same logic. I hope this makes sense. I should also mention that if you keep going down that table, there will be another 3, 9, 22, and so on.

Comment: does meta_key 3 always = DRYS or could it be different

Comment: It can be different. It will be DRYS or some other name. It seems that the number 3 is the constant for those kinds of values. Meaning DRYS and another name should basically be characterized by being in the same column. I'm not sure why this table is listed the way it is.

Comment: Im still properly confused as to exactly what you want the out come to look like. Sorry you need to be more detailed. This will go on forever otherwise

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta
WHERE meta_key IN(3, 9, 22,23)
```

Comment: This is just a shortened version of the query that was posted

Comment: Hi Carlos, Thank you for your help! I tried this and unfortunately, it gave me the same outcome as the after photo above.

Comment: HI Juergen, Maybe you could post a draw of what you need to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Carlos. I don't know how to do that. But this description might help more: I think a better way of describing it is that I want every row from the meta_value column in the first photo above to be in its own column. Only, I don't need every single one of those rows and I realize I would probably have to make column names for each. I'm not sure if this is even possible.